# Why isn't Task.Wait(timeout) returning immediately for a synchronous, one-operation task?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I have a library call that I need to wrap in a timeout, because it hangs for certain inputs.

It appears that `Task.Wait(timeout)` is the simplest way to do this.  But it is not doing what I would expect.  Here is a test case (for a linqpad-like test environment):

```
class A { public int X; }

public static void Main() {
    var o = new A { X = 0 };

    new Task(() => { o.X = 1; }).RunSynchronously();
    o.X.Dump(); // Says "1" immediately

    new Task(() => { o.X = 2; }).Wait(2000);
    o.X.Dump(); // Says "1" after 2 seconds
}
```

Why does the second call time out, and never perform the assignment?  Am I misunderstanding the API?

**UPDATE**: @ThomasLevesque's answer is correct, that I needed to `Run` the task.  However, I am now finding that the `Wait` timeout is not effective.  My actual case involves the SmartXLS component.  I replaced this

```
// hangs for some workbooks (as in, never returns and hoses the process, or falls to request timeout)
rangeDefinition = _workbook.getDefinedName(rangeName);
```

with this

```
// exactly the same as above.  Timeout has no effect.
var task = Task<string>.Run(() => _workbook.getDefinedName(rangeName));
if (!task.Wait(millisecondsTimeout: 4000)) {
    throw new Exception("Could not read range " + rangeName);
}

rangeDefinition = task.Result;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your second task is never actually started (which also explains why X is still 1, not 2), so it can't complete. Usually, you shouldn't use the `Task` constructor, but rather the `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew` methods.

Comment: Thanks, and that also works for my actual case (where I need a result from the task).  Thanks for helping with a basic questions, I'm new to the TPL.

Comment: That said... it isn't working for my production case.  That is, the library call is still timing out, even with this wrapper.  It's a call to a managed Excel API.  Even if it just completely spins, the scheduler should be able to break it out, right?

Comment: @harpo, I'm not sure I understand your scenario... What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I have one call into a third-party component that sometimes hangs (trying to get the definition of an Excel range).  I guess it's caught in an infinite loop -- not sure, the code is obfuscated.  I need a way to call it with an appropriate fallback for those cases.  All of the resources I've found point to TPL, but these timeouts seem to have no effect.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up.  I've put my actual code in the question.  For what it's worth, I've gotten the same result from similar approaches, such as [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/11/10/10235834.aspx).

Comment: @harpo, do you mean that Wait(4000) doesn't return false after 4 seconds? I did a test on my side and it's working fine...

Comment: Thanks again for the follow-up... the timeout did work in a simpler test, so I guess it's something in my production environment (which is ASP.NET).  Thanks for your help.